# inheritance : asmx webservice alway return subclass

Tags: c#, serialization, inheritance, asmx

I have a problem with an asmx webservices. I have those object

```
public class animal
{
    public string id = null;
    public string name = null;
}

public class dog: animals
{
    public string surname = null;
    public string color = null;
}
```

and a webservice

```
public animal GetAnimal()
{
  animal result = new dog();
  return result;
}
```

the problem is that my webservice alway return a dog. Is there an easy way so it can return an animal?
(I see 2 solutions that I don't like:

```
animal result = new animal();
```

or

```
animal resultDog = new dog();
animal result = new animal();
result.id = resultDog.id
result.color = resultDog.color
```

)

Comment: What does your code consuming the webservice look like?

Answer (score 3):

*the problem is that my webservice alway return a dog*

It returns a dog type because ... thats what it returns

```
public animal GetAnimal()
{
  animal result = **new dog();**
  return result;
}
```

Your consuming code should be able to refernce it as an animal type without any problems:

```
animal a = GetAnimal();
a.id="id";
a.name="name";
```

Can you be more specific on what error or problem your having?